# How to combine Cross Join and String Agg in Bigquery with date time difference

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I am trying to go from the following table

```
| user_id | touch     | Date       | Purchase Amount
| 1       | Impression| 2020-09-12 |0
| 1       | Impression| 2020-10-12 |0
| 1       | Purchase  | 2020-10-13 |125$
| 1       | Email     | 2020-10-14 |0
| 1       | Impression| 2020-10-15 |0
| 1       | Purchase  | 2020-10-30 |122
| 2       | Impression| 2020-10-15 |0
| 2       | Impression| 2020-10-16 |0
| 2       | Email     | 2020-10-17 |0
```

to

```
| user_id | path                           | Number of days between First  Touch and Purchase | Purchase Amount
| 1       | Impression,Impression,Purchase | 2020-10-13(Purchase) - 2020-09-12 (Impression) |125$
| 1       |  Email,Impression, Purchase    | 2020-10-30(Purchase) - 2020-10-14(Email) | 122$
| 2       | Impression, Impression, Email  | 2020-12-31 (Fixed date) - 2020-10-15(Impression) | 0$
```

In essence, I am trying to create a new row for each unique user in the table every time a 'Purchase' is encountered in a comma-separated string.

Also, take the difference between the first touch and first purchase for each unique user. When a new row is created we do the same for the same user as show in the example above.

From the little I have gathered I need to use a mixture of cross join and string agg but I tried using a case statement within string agg and was not able to get to the required result.

Is there a better way to do it in SQL (Bigquery).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select user_id, 
  string_agg(touch order by date) path,
  date_diff(max(date), min(date), day) days,
  sum(amount) amount
from (
  select user_id, touch, date, amount,
    countif(touch = 'Purchase') over win grp
  from `project.dataset.table`
  window win as (partition by user_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
)
group by user_id, grp
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

> another change, in case there is no Purchase in the touch we calculate the number of days from a fixed window we have set. How can I add this to the query above?

```
select user_id, 
  string_agg(touch order by date) path,
  date_diff(if(countif(touch = 'Purchase') = 0, '2020-12-31', max(date)), min(date), day) days,
  sum(amount) amount
from (
  select user_id, touch, date, amount,
    countif(touch = 'Purchase') over win grp
  from `project.dataset.table`
  window win as (partition by user_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
)
group by user_id, grp
```

with output

[image]

Comment: @ Mikhail, Sorry I had to make another change, in case there is no Purchase in the touch we calculate the number of days from a fixed window we have set. How can I add this to the query above?

Comment: you should STOP changing your question - and rather try something by yourself based on three answers you already got! if you will still have problem - post new question and we will help you. Meantime, consider voting up and accept answer, otherwise, i don't see reason to continue answering :o)

Comment: consider voting up the answer, meantime I can add that extra condition you (as looks like I am going to have few minutes for it) :o) but as I said - you should not change your question especially after answer(s) provided already!

Answer (score 0):

Means you need solution which divides row if there is purchase in touch.

Use following query:

```
Select user_id,
       Aggregation function according to your requirement,
       Sum(purchase_amount)
  From
(Select t.*,
       Sum(case when touch = 'Purchase' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by date) as sm
  From t) t
Group by user_id, sm
```

Comment: This would put each  "Purchase" at the beginning of each group rather than at the end.

Comment: @Popeye I just added one more column  i would need to aggregate. Sorry about the change

Comment: @GMB , I have clearly mentioned to use aggregate function according to requirement.

Answer (score 0):

We could approach this as a gaps-and-island problem, where every island ends with a purchase. How do we define the groups? By counting how many purchases we have *ahead* (current row included) - so with a descending sort in the query.

```
select user_id, string_agg(touch order by date), 
    min(date) as first_date, max(date) as max_date,
    date_diff(max(date), min(date)) as cnt_days
from (
    select t.*,
        countif(touch = 'Purchase') over(partition by user_id order by date desc) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
group by user_id, grp
```

Comment: I just added one more column  i would need to aggregate. Sorry about the change

Comment: @VardaanKhanted: just add `sum(amount)` to the `select` clause in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a value for each row that corresponds to the number of instances where `table.touch = 'Purchase'`, which can then be used to group on:

```
with r as (select row_number() over(order by t1.user_id) rid, t1.* from table t1)
select t3.user_id, group_concat(t3.touch), sum(t3.amount), date_diff(max(t3.date), min(t3.date))
from (select 
       (select sum(r1.touch = 'Purchase' AND r1.rid < r2.rid) from r r1) c1, r2.* from r r2
    ) t3 
group by t3.c1;
```